# LibGDX Button and Table Layout

Tags: libgdx

I want to change the position of the Buttons inside a table, I tried setting their X and Y, or get their position when adding the Buttons on the Table, but it didn't work. It always aligns the button on the center.

Code:

```
    TextureAtlas ta = new TextureAtlas("Comecar.txt");
    final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion as = ta.findRegion("comeca");
    final TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion as2 = ta.findRegion("comecaversao2");
    myTexRegionDrawable2 = new TextureRegionDrawable(as2);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(as);
    myTexRegionDrawable.setMinHeight(300);
    myTexRegionDrawable.setMinWidth(260);
    myTexRegionDrawable2.setMinHeight(300);
    myTexRegionDrawable2.setMinWidth(260);
    b = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable);
    op = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable2);
    op.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        }
    });
    b.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            gdxGame.setScreen(new Janela2(gdxGame));
        }
    });
    t = new Table();
    t.add(b);//I tried setting the position here
    t.add(op);
    t.setFillParent(true);
    stage.addActor(t);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add an actor inside a table, its position is always derived from the alignments of the table layout. The only solution to re-position the actor you might then get would be playing with its alignment and padding (which I believe does not suit the needs in many cases).